# Split a row into multiple rows in csv based on column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv as shown below and need to parse the csv into multiple rows based on value in column 3 to load into db...

Due to restrictions I can use only `import csv` module to do this function and that is where I am stuck and problem i am facing is if i write a insert query.. it's not fetching all the rows.. it's fetching only the last record in each for loop and inserting into table

```
1,2,3,4,5
10,20,30,50
100,200,300,400
```

Possible code:

```
if column 3 = 'y' else 'n' in column 4 in table
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,y
1,2,4,n
1,2,5,n
10,20,30,y
10,20,50,n
100,200,300,y
100,200,400,n
```

here is my code

```
import csv

import os

#Test-new to clean.csv
fRead=open("clean.csv")
csv_r=csv.reader(fRead)
#to skip first two lines
leave=0
for record in csv_r:
    if leave<2:
        leave+=1
        continue
    #storing the values of column 3,4,5 as an array
    JMU=[]

    for t in [2, 3, 4]:
        if not(record[t] in ["", "NA"]):
            JMU.append(record[t].strip())
            #print len(JMU)
            #print "2"
    if len(JMU)==0:
        #print "0"
        pass
    else:

#check if the name contains WRK
        isWRK1 = "Table"
        for data in JMU:
            print data
            if data[:3].lower()=="wrk" or data[-3:].lower()=="wrk":
                isWRK1="Work"
                print isWRK
            else:
                isWRK = "table"
        #check if column 2 value is "Yes" or "No"       
        fourthColumn="N"
        if not(record[2] in ["", "NA"]):
            #print record[2]
            if record[3].strip().lower()=="no":
              #  print record[3]
                fourthColumn = "I"
            else:
                fourthColumn = "N"

        for i in JMU:
            iWRK = "Table"
            if record[2]==i:
                newRecord = [record[0], record[1], i, fourthColumn, isWRK,]
                #print newRecord
            elif record[3] == i:


                newRecord = [record[0], record[1], i, "N", isWRK]
                #print newRecord
            else:

                newRecord = [record[0], record[1], i, "N", isWRK]
        print ("insert into table (column_a,column_b,column_c,column_d,column_e) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"% (record[0],record[1],record[2],record[3],record[4]))



fRead.close()
fWrite.close()
```

Comment: Is there a problem with the solution you have, or are you looking for a place to get started?

Comment: You need to attempt this yourself.  This is not a place for people to write code for you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.  From what you've posted, it appears that you don't know how to read a CSV file -- which is something you look up on line.

Comment: If you haven't already, I recommend that you skim the official documentation for the `csv` module.  Pay especial attention to the code examples there: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: What on Earth is this supposed to mean: `if column 3 = 'y else 'n' in column 4 in table`?

Comment: @PRUNE , sorry.. I am newbie to stackoverflow.. from now i will post the code i have written so that i can get suggestion from it...

Comment: We still need you to post the applicable code.  You've posted only one line, and that has syntax errors.

Comment: @Prune updated the code in the orginal post

Comment: Thanks; down-vote and close vote retracted.  Did the given answer solve your problem?  If so, please up-vote and accept it, so SO can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to keep the 1st 2 columns as constant and make a new row for every next number present on the same input line.

Initially I came up with this 1-liner `awk` command:

```
$ cat data 
1,2,3,4,5
10,20,30,50
100,200,300,400
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) print $1, $2, $i, (i==3?"y":"n")}' data 
1,2,3,y
1,2,4,n
1,2,5,n
10,20,30,y
10,20,50,n
100,200,300,y
100,200,400,n
```

and then I replicated the same into python using the `csv` module:

```
import csv
with open('data', 'r') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        l=list(map(int, row))
        for i in range(2, len(l)):
            print(l[0], l[1], l[i], 'y' if i==2 else 'n', sep=',')
```

and here is a sample run which is same as `awk`'s output:

```
1,2,3,y
1,2,4,n
1,2,5,n
10,20,30,y
10,20,50,n
100,200,300,y
100,200,400,n
```